# mariadbd [Warning] Aborted connection 5389 to db: 'nextcloud' user: 'ncadmin' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)

Tags: mariadb

Ubuntu 22.04LTS
Nextcloud 26.0.1
Mariadb Server version: 10.6.12-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.11 (cli) (built: Feb 22 2023 22:56:18)

When restarting the apache service, in some cases, not always, the apache service crashes.
In syslog:

> Apr 25 09:20:01 nc CRON[29605]: (root) CMD (apachectl -k graceful)
>
> Apr 25 09:20:03 nc mariadbd[29518]: 2023-04-25  9:20:03 32 [Warning] Aborted connection 32 to db: 'nextcloud' user: 'ncadmin' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
>
> Apr 25 09:20:03 nc mariadbd[29518]: 2023-04-25  9:20:03 33 [Warning] Aborted connection 33 to db: 'nextcloud' user: 'ncadmin' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
>
> Apr 25 09:20:04 nc mariadbd[29518]: 2023-04-25  9:20:04 34 [Warning] Aborted connection 34 to db: 'nextcloud' user: 'ncadmin' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)

In apport.log:

> ERROR: apport (pid 29728) Tue Apr 25 09:22:21 2023: called for pid 29715, signal 11, core limit 0, dump mode 2
>
> ERROR: apport (pid 29728) Tue Apr 25 09:22:21 2023: not creating core for pid with dump mode of 2
>
> ERROR: apport (pid 29728) Tue Apr 25 09:22:21 2023: executable: /usr/sbin/apache2 (command line "/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start")
>
> ERROR: apport (pid 29728) Tue Apr 25 09:22:21 2023: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
>
> ERROR: apport (pid 29728) Tue Apr 25 09:22:22 2023: this executable already crashed 2 times, ignoring

In Apache (error.log):

> [Tue Apr 25 09:19:54.460226 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 29595] AH00163: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/3.0.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Tue Apr 25 09:19:54.460465 2023] [core:notice] [pid 29595] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
>
> [Tue Apr 25 09:20:01.385328 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 29595] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
>
> [Tue Apr 25 09:20:01.463608 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 29595] AH00163: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/3.0.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Tue Apr 25 09:20:01.463648 2023] [core:notice] [pid 29595] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
>
> [Tue Apr 25 09:20:03.473403 2023] [core:notice] [pid 29595] AH00051: child pid 29609 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
>
> [Tue Apr 25 09:20:03.473525 2023] [core:notice] [pid 29595] AH00051: child pid 29610 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
>
> [Tue Apr 25 09:20:04.477501 2023] [core:notice] [pid 29595] AH00051: child pid 29613 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2

What is the problem, how to fix it?

Comment: On the database side "Error reading communication packet" typically means that a client closed the connection without sending a close command on the mysql/mariadb protocol level first. E.g. in the C API this is done using the `mysql_close()` function. A client process crashing is one of the possible causes for such a connection loss. So the database log message is a collateral of the apache2 crash, not the cause.
Enabling core dumps for the apache2 process(es) may provide more info on the actual crash reason ...